# react-navigation 5 navigate multiple routes at once

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

Is there a better way of navigating multiple routes than the following one?

```
   NavigatorService.navigate('Screen1', params);
   NavigatorService.navigate('Screen2', params);
```

Where `Screen1` and `Screen2` are Siblings in the same stack navigator.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? creating a navigation history with Screen1 and Screen2?

Comment: yes, the end result would that when you hit back on Screen2, you go to Screen1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick example I created on [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/navigation-reset). Basically, you can create an array of screens, and use the reset function to create the history.

```
navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
              index: 4,
              routes: [
                {
                  name: 'Stack',
                  params: { screen: 'StackView1' },
                },
                {
                  name: 'Stack',
                  params: { screen: 'StackView2' },
                },
                {
                  name: 'Stack1',
                  params: { screen: 'Stack1View1' },
                },
                {
                  name: 'Stack1',
                  params: { screen: 'Stack1View2' },
                },
                {
                  name: 'Stack1',
                  params: { screen: 'Stack1View3' },
                },
              ],
            })
          );
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it and also preserve the current stack:

```
navigator.dispatch((state) => {
    const newRoutes = [...state.routes, ...routesToAdd];
    
    return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        routes: newRoutes,
        index: newRoutes.length - 1,
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It really came in handy for my project. I dug a little deeper and found that this is covered in the RN documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset